# in visual studio 2015 community c++, how do I fix warning C4838: conversion from 'unsigned int' to 'int' requires a narrowing conversion

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to write some straight c++ on win32 API (no mfc).
With this more modern c++ compiler I get:

warning C4838: conversion from 'unsigned int' to 'int' requires a narrowing conversion

It happens in this code:

```
EvMap<DlgCtl> DlgCtl::_evMap [] = {
    {IDC_LIST, NM_CLICK, & DlgCtl::Pik},
    {0}
};
```

riiiiight in front of the closing brace.  The 0 for control id means end of array.
This code maps a control id and event id to a local function similar to how MFC does.

I guess a narrowing conversion means you're losing precision in the implicit conversion of an unsigned in to int (as an unsigned can hold > 32767 and an int can't).
I'm not sure what the unsigned int is.  There's a 0, but that's a signed int, right?
The below code is using the list to dispatch class local functions in a winproc-ish class.

```
template <class T>
struct EvMap {int ctrl, evnt;  void (T::* func)(LPARAM l);};


template <class T>
bool DoEvMap (T *ths, EvMap<T> *evMap, int ctrl, int evnt, LPARAM l)
{
//DBG("DoEvMap ctrl=`d evnt=`d", ctrl, evnt);
    for (int i = 0;  evMap [i].ctrl;  i++) {
//DBG(" - check ctrl=`d evnt=`d", evMap [i].ctrl, evMap [i].evnt);
       if ((ctrl == evMap [i].ctrl) && (evnt == evMap [i].evnt))
           {(ths->*(evMap [i].func)) (l);   return true;}
    }
    return false;
}
```

I don't want to turn off the warning cuz that's just bad form.  I tried putting a static_cast<int>(0) in there for the 0, but same warning.

How can I get on with life with this pesky compiler?

Comment: 0 is signed int. 0u is unsigned. The narrowing shoulld be happening because 0 is supplied as the address of the function - and int does not suffice in 64bit.

Comment: @SergeyA The `0` is supplied as `ctrl`, not as `func`.

Comment: pretty sure it's those control ids.  They seem to be defined as an offset from NM_FIRST which is a 0u.  (see below answer)  Why?  Cuz microsoft hates me.  I don't thiiiiink I'm using 64 bit, but I better go check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `unsigned int` the compiler is warning about is either `IDC_LIST` or `NM_CLICK`, since obviously `0` is not an `unsigned int`.

So either of those two should be signed, *or* `ctrl` or `evnt` should be unsigned.

Comment: they look like ints to me...
<pre>
    #define IDC_LIST                                1076
    #define NM_CLICK                (NM_FIRST-2)    // uses NMCLICK struct
</pre>
OH WAIT...
<pre>
    #define NM_FIRST                (0U-  0U)       // generic to all controls
</pre>
Dang it.  Looks like this may get messy.  But at least I'm on to somethin...

Thank you sir.

Comment: argh.  can't figure out how to format code to save my life but THAT was my answer sir.

microsoft defined NM_FIRST  as  0u  
 
So I have my answer - thank you.  

I hope this doesn't mean too much code uglification but i suspect it does...